# Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge results in error

Tags: firebase, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I have started to host a React app on Firebase including Github workflows (firebase-hosting-merge.yml and firebase-hosting-pull-request.yml).

While I could solve the the error in firebase-hosting-pull-request.yml using [Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR faild in github actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862219/deploy-to-firebase-hosting-on-pr-faild-in-github-actions), I cannot solve the error ("Error: Process completed with exit code 1.") in firebase-hosting-merge.yml.

1. Does anybody know how to solve that?
2. How would I remove the workflows (as I don't really need them)? (Can I simply remove the folder ".github/workflows"?)

Code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've also recently faced "*Error: Process completed with exit code 1.*" triggered by `firebase-hosting-merge.yml`. Nevertheless, we managed to solve this.

In our case it turned out that we have not been using the latest Node version for our React app, whereas the action was trying to build the app based on the latest Node release by default and some dependencies were conflicting with our build. To resolve this, we managed to configure the `yaml` workflow into using a specific Node version.

Afterwads, we faced "*Error: Process completed with exit code 1*" again but for a different reason: our app was built with Node.js v14.15.4 which turned out to be incompatible with  Firebase CLI v11.30.0, so we had to update Node version of our app to overcome this and, finally, Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge started to succeed.

Here's the final structure of our `firebase-hosting-merge.yml` file that works for our React app (we had to manually update the default file generated by Firebase CLI commands to incorporate all the necessary changes):

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
env:
  REACT_APP_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_API_KEY }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID }}
  REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL }}
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [17.4.0]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/
        
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3      
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - run: |
              npm install
              npm ci && npm run build --if-present      
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_APPNAME }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: APPNAME
```